# How can I use shorthand if with return

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make condition with shorthand if and use return in condition how can I do something like this

Here is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $all = User::all()
    $all = $this->calculatePercent($all);
    return view('dashboard.index');
}
```

I want to make condition

```
If (!empty($user)){
    $user = $user;
} else {
    return 0
}
```

How can I do something like this :

```
public function calculatePercent($user) 
{
    $query = !empty($user) ? $user : return 0;
}
```

**Update I want to do some thing like this in my function**

```
public function calculatePercent($user) 
{
    $user = !empty($user) ? $user : return 0;
    foreach ($user as $item) {
        $percentSell[] = ($item->total * 100)/$item->target;
    }
    return $percentSell;
}
```

Comment: Not clear what is expected return from `calculatePercent` in case user is not empty. Maybe `return !empty($user) ? $user : 0;` is good enough?

Comment: You can't use return for only one of the conditions  `$foo = true ? return true : false;`  You'll get `syntax error, unexpected 'return'`  its a feature not a bug.

Comment: I update my querstion

Comment: that's great!, Unfortunately you still cant do it .... lol

Comment: yes it syntax . error and I want to know how to do something like  if empty retrun 0 ;  can I use with short hand ifelse ?

Comment: so I've to use full if else ? @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: You don't need the brackets `if(true) return true; else $var = false;`  Which really isn't much longer.  You only need `{ }` for muti-line if's.  You can't use short hand because the return is expected as the end of the scope you are in, and this also doesn't work `$true = return false;` because you can't assign return to something.

Comment: Thanks that what I'm looking for Can u place it in Answer I'll mark @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: Just wannt to know how to clean code lol. niceeee  ty@ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: One thing to remember, is short code is not always "clean" code.  Clean code for me is readable code. Not to say to write it longer then it needs to be, but to much short hand can make it messy and harder to read.  One should be able to glance at code and easily see what the structure of it is.  Whenever I code something (which is all the time) Readability is only second to it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi unfortunately you currently cannot return from one of the condition of a trinary expression (short hand if).

Doing:

```
$foo = true ? return true : false;
```

Give you

```
syntax error, unexpected 'return'
```

That said for single line `if's` you can omit the `{}` curly brackets

```
if(true) return true; else $foo = false;
```

Which really is not that much longer.  I'm not sure exactly why this is the case (cant do it in trinary).  It could be because it has sort of an implied return. It could be because returning ends whatever scope you are in and the trinary cannot be completed because of that.  Or it could be because it can do assignment such as this (as seen above):

```
$foo = true ? return true : false;
$foo = return true; //this gives the same syntax error
```

Well for whatever reason, it's just not possible in the current version of PHP.  Perhaps sometime in the future they may do it, but it seems like a low priority sort of thing, so I wouldn't hold my breath ... lol

Just for completeness you can change this:

```
$query = !empty($user) ? $user : return 0;
```

Into

```
if(!empty($user))$query=$user;else return 0;
```

Also notice you can remove spaces in certain places. Shorthand stuff like this is fine, but there is something to be said about readability.  For this it's probably fine, but readability is very important in code and it's much more important then being concise and short, IMO.

When I write code my priorities are

- that it achieves the desired result
- that it is readable
- that it is concise (not bloated)
- that it preforms well

If it doesn't do what it's supposed to it's worthless, if you can't read it it's hard to maintain and make sure it does what it's supposed to.  If it has a lot of unnecessary bloat it's hard to read and probably performs poorly.  Once all those are met, then if I need to I will try to improve the performance of it.

Anyway happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
public function calculatePercent($user) 
{
    if (empty($user)) return 0; // if $user is empty code ends here with return 0.

    foreach ($user as $item) {
        $percentSell[] = ($item->total * 100)/$item->target;
    }

    return $percentSell;
}
```